# conntrack with LVS

Tags: iptables, lvs

I'm trying to use conntrack ftp with lvs (snat), documentations say that I need to echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/conntrack but this file doesn't exist on my system, do you know why ?

I already loaded nf_nat_ftp and ip_vs_ftp

> # ls /proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs/
>
> am_droprate  amemthresh  cache_bypass  drop_entry  drop_packet  expire_nodest_conn  expire_quiescent_template  nat_icmp_send  secure_tcp  sync_threshold

Maybe because of this setting, my conntrack rule doesn't work :(

My system is a Debian Lenny with a 2.6.32 kernel (2.6.32-bpo.5-686).

Thanks for your help.

sysctl -a | grep conntrack output :

> net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_unacknowledged = 300
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose = 1
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal = 0
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 180
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct = 1
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events = 1
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_events_retry_timeout = 15
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 65536
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_count = 129
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_buckets = 16384
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_checksum = 1
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_log_invalid = 0
>   net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_expect_max = 256
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_generic_timeout = 600
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent = 120
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_sent2 = 120
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_syn_recv = 60
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 432000
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_last_ack = 30
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_time_wait = 120
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close = 10
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_loose = 1
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_be_liberal = 0
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_udp_timeout = 30
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_udp_timeout_stream = 180
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_icmp_timeout = 30
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 65536
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_count = 129
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_buckets = 16384
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_checksum = 1
>   net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_log_invalid = 0
>   net.nf_conntrack_max = 65536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NFCT patch](http://www.ssi.bg/~ja/nfct/) to Linux kernel.

Comment: You are right, conntrack with LVS need this patche if kernel version is less than 2.6.36, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what is ""LVS, but there's `ip_conntrack_ftp` module which handles FTP innards to get through NAT properly.

Comment: LVS is a load balancing solution, it modify the path of classic routings packets and standard conntrack can't work anymore.